# When dates are on the x axis, how do i set the x axis intervals to months?

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

Hi i have 2 arrays which are on the lines of:

```
array1 = [datetime.date(2014, 3, 3), datetime.date(2014, 2, 19), datetime.date(2014, 7, 13), datetime.date(2014, 5, 11), datetime.date(2014, 6, 13), datetime.date(2014, 1, 20)]

array2 = 1,5,8,9,4,6
```

Here is the code i have to plot the 2 arrays:

```
plt.plot_date((aray1), (array2), 'ro')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Quantity', fontsize=12)
plt.savefig('plot4.png')
```

My arrays are a lot bigger than the ones above, so my dates are squashed together and dont fit on the x axis. So, How do i set the x axis intervals to months, so the dates im plotting can slot into the correct month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the dataset you provided doesn't reproduce the problem, nevertheless: what you are looking for is the exact use case of a [matplotlib example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo2.html) applied on your data.

```
import numpy
from datetime import datetime
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, MonthLocator

t = numpy.array([datetime(2014, 3, 3),
                 datetime(2014, 2, 19),
                 datetime(2014, 7, 13),
                 datetime(2014, 5, 11),
                 datetime(2014, 6, 13),
                 datetime(2014, 1, 20)])

values = numpy.array([1, 5, 8, 9, 4, 6])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot_date(t, values, 'ro')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('Quantity', fontsize=12)

months = MonthLocator()
monthsFmt = DateFormatter("%b '%y")
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(monthsFmt)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works if i hardcode my date array in. But because my array is the format datetime.date instead of just datetime, it doesnt work. How can i avoid this?

Comment: I am using this code to convert my dates array1 = [dt.datetime.strptime(a,'%Y-%m-%d').date() for a in array1]

Comment: link moved and deprecated!